# Substitution of a couple of math-greek font files only within cmr family

Tags: math-mode, fonts, greek, metafont

I am trying to use (XeLaTeX)  with fonts MinionPro but for *greek letters in math mode only* I am substituting cmr math greek instead of Mignon (or MNSymbol) using commands such as:

```
\usepackage[mathlf]{MinionPro} 
\DeclareSymbolFont{Letters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}   and then a series of:
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{11}
```

through the greek alphabet. This is successful. But to increase the weights of the glyphs a tiny fraction, I have created (using MF) fonts such as cmmi10ptthicker, cmmi11ptthicker.

Q How do I incorporate these fonts throughout a document? 
How can I ensure the selection of cmmi10ptthicker.tfm /etc ?

Comment: Find OMLcmm.fd and make a copy with the name OMLcmmthicker.fd. Change in the copy the references to the fonts. Then use `\DeclareSymbolFont{Letters}{OML}{cmmthicker}{m}{it}`. This assumes that your fonts are correctly installed and works.

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks. But if I make an identical copy of OMLcmm.fd (found in /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmm.fd ), call it cmm2, from the following MWE:

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks. But if I make an identical copy of OMLcmm.fd (found in /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmm.fd  I believe this is a standard installation), call it cmm2, from the following MWE:   '\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{‌​Letters}{OML}{cmm2}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{11}
\begin{document}
%$\alpha$
\end{document}'  I get the error for \DeclareMathSymbol on Line: 4: LaTeX Error: Symbol font `Letters' is not defined.

Comment: @Ulrike - sorry the `Letters' was due to an invisible 0 width character before Letters on my screen (!) - but I still am getting `Font Shape OML/cmm2/m/it undefined`

Comment: You should call your copy OMLcmm2.fd. Also look in the file and check if there are cmm which should be changed to cmm2.